# What to do with singular fit in mixed-effects model when all random effects are required by theory?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm using repeat cross-sectional data to examine growth trajectories in adult BMI by birth year.

I've structured the data as a pseudo-panel. The data look something like this:

| id | year | birth | age | bmi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1991 | 42 | 1949 | 29 |
| 2 | 1992 | 50 | 1952 | 26 |
| 3 | 2007 | 60 | 1947 | 24 |
| 4 | 2004 | 25 | 1979 | 25 |
| 5 | 2017 | 34 | 1973 | 30 |

I'm trying to run `lme4` models of the form:

```
lmer(bmi ~ 1 + age + (1 + age | birth_year), df)
```

In other words, I'm using the data to examine variation in how the mean level of BMI has developed in a set of cohorts as they age.

I've tried to run the model, but I get singular fit. The correlation between the random intercepts and slopes is ~= 1.

I've seen advice that I should simplify the model by dropping one or the other of the random effects, but *a priori* I expect the correlation between the random intercepts and slopes to be very high: successive cohorts are likely to have higher initial BMI (say at age 20) and growth in BMI (e.g. change from age 20 to 64). Throwing one random effect out would stop me being able to study what I want to study.

Another bit of advice I've seen is to use `brms::brm` or `rstanarm::stan_lmer` instead, but I have quite a big dataset (~ 165k observations, with 65 `birth_y` groups). I've tried running it, but it doesn't seem to be getting past initialising the model.

Does anyone know what I should do, please?

Thanks

---

**Edit:** @RobertLong asked for model output from the correlated and uncorrelated random slope models. I have added weights to the regressions, which I didn't mention in the origin question as I thought this was unecessary complexity.

**Correlated Random Effects**

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: bmi ~ 1 + age + (1 + age | birth_year)
   Data: df
Weights: wt

REML criterion at convergence: 999040.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9544 -0.6856 -0.1569  0.5088 10.6146 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 birth_year (Intercept)  0.1954  0.4421       
            age          3.6932  1.9218   1.00
 Residual               23.6166  4.8597       
Number of obs: 165871, groups:  birth_year, 65

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 23.93920    0.06392   374.5
age          6.77508    0.25377    26.7

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr)
age 0.660 
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

**Uncorrelated Random Effects**

````
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: bmi ~ 1 + age + (1 | birth_year) + (0 + age | birth_year)
   Data: df
Weights: wt

REML criterion at convergence: 999073.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.9988 -0.6856 -0.1566  0.5086 10.6144 

Random effects:
 Groups       Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 birth_year   (Intercept)  0.2253  0.4746  
 birth_year.1 age          4.4265  2.1039  
 Residual                 23.6156  4.8596  
Number of obs: 165871, groups:  birth_year, 65

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) 24.05705    0.07418  324.30
age          6.52151    0.28643   22.77

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
    (Intr)
age -0.179
```
````

Comment: Did you conduct a sample size computation to ensure that you have sufficient data to estimate the random effects and the correlation between them ? Also, does the model without correlation converge without singularity ?

Comment: Thanks. By model without correlation, do you mean `lmer(bmi ~ 1 + age + (1 | birth_year) + (0 + age | birth_year), df)`? That model converges (and actually using `ranef()`, the correlation between the random effects is 0.78). I didn't do a sample size calculation formally, but I specified that a given `birth_year` has to be observed at 5+ ages. Looking at the sample sizes, the minimum observations for a `birth_year*age` combination is 31 (and the minimum observations per `birth_year` is 230), so the sample is much bigger than when I've done mixed effects models with e.g. longitudinal data

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. Does centering `age` help ?

Comment: @RobertLong In theory, if the MLE of the correlation is one before mean-centering it will necessarily also be equal to one after mean-centering.

Comment: @JarleTufto centering the time variable for analysis of change is often needed for inferential purposes - for example see 
Tennant, P.W., Arnold, K.F., Ellison, G.T. and Gilthorpe, M.S., 2019. Analyses of'change scores' do not estimate causal effects in observational data. arXiv preprint arXiv:1907.02764...Tu, Y.K. and Gilthorpe, M.S., 2007. Revisiting the relation between change and initial value: a review and evaluation. Statistics in medicine, 26(2), pp.443-457.

Comment: @RobertLong I agree that it can help with numerical issues but in the case of the random intercept slope model condidered by the OP, mean-centering only amounts to a form of reparameterization of the model.

Comment: @JarleTufto agreed,  and that alternative parameterisation can be important for inference on the corelation between the random effects.

Comment: @JarleTufto this is good reference on the matter: Blance A, Tu Y-K, Gilthorpe MS. A multilevel modelling solution to mathematical coupling. Statistical Methods
in Medical Research 2005; 14:553–565.

Comment: @RobertLong, I got the same problem after centering age. I'm interested how `mod <- lmer(bmi ~ 1 + age + (1 | birth_year) + (0 + age | birth_year), df)` purportedly specifies zero correlation between the random effects, but in practice, `cor(ranef(mod)[[1]]) = 0.78`. Does this mean the predictions are valid for my research purposes (what are trajectories in mean BMI by cohort) even though the assumption of uncorrelated random effects is unlikely to be true? I would imagine that the `ranef()` correlation is biased downwards.

Comment: Please add the summary() output for both your singular model and also the zero correlation model.

Comment: @RobertLong, thanks. I've added the model output now as an edit to the original post.

Comment: So it looks like the variance of the random intercepts is too small to estimate alongside the correlation.

Comment: @RobertLong, if I center age, then the variance of the random intercepts should increase increases, but I still get a singular fit. What would you drop in this scenario - the correlation or the random effects? I am using this model to extract estimated trajectories for each `birth_year`, so that the `ranef()` estimates are still correlated when running the uncorrelated effects model still seems like the model is useful.

Comment: I am not understanding the motivation for inclusion of random effects here.  And shouldn't age and birth year be too collinear to include both?

Comment: @FrankHarrell, I'm using repeat cross-sectional survey data from 1991-2019. A cohort (`birth_year`) can be present in up to 28 survey years, so  they shouldn't be too collinear (age and cohort together are collinear with period, of course), though some cohorts are followed as little as 5 years (e.g. 1995 is followed from 2015 when they reach age 20). I'm using random effects as I want: to estimate growth in *mean* BMI by cohort as that cohort ages; understand how that growth compares with other cohorts; and to reduce over-fitting by not modelling individual trajectories with fixed effects.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The last part doesn't follow though.  You won't have overfitting with fixed effects unless you treat age or birth year as a categorical variable.  Since the cohort variable is continuous it should be modeled continuously (but flexibly, e.g., using regression splines).  Still not a reason for random effects.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, OK, will try that. Thank you!